# Count lexographically sorted substrings

Tags: algorithm

Given a string S of length N. String S is made of lower case English alphabets. We need to counthow many substrings of S are sorted.

Given the string S, we need to count the number of sorted substrings of S.

**A string s is lexicographically sorted if s[i] ≤ s[i+1] where 1 ≤ i ≤ N-1 (consider 1-based indexing).**

**Example** :  Let String S="bba" then answer is 4

**Explanation** : Substrings of 'bba' are: b, b, a, bb, ba, bba
Out of these 6 substrings, 4 ('b', 'b', 'a' and 'bb') substrings are sorted. So the answer is 4.

My current solution is no better than a brute force . That is to check each substring and then check if its sorted or not. But string length can be 1000000 so O(N^2) approach won't work out. So what can be better solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make two indexes - Left and Right. Set them both to the first symbol index of the string. Increment Right while `s[Right] ≤ s[Right+1]`.
When next symbol violates an order, you have substring `ss = s[Left..Right]`, all substrings of ss are sorted too.
Find their number through ss length:

```
k = Right - Left + 1
```

You have k one-char substrings, k-1 two-char ones... and 1 k-length substring.

```
N = 1 + 2 +... + k = k * (k + 1) / 2
```

Add N to the overall number of susbstrings, move Left and Right to (Right + 1) and continue.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long int
ll sum(ll n)
{
    return (n*(n+1))/2;
}
int main()
{
    int test;
    cin>>test;
    while(test--)
    {
        int l;
        cin>>l;
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        ll ans=0, length=1;
        for(int i=1;i<s.size();i++)
        {
            //increment till it is not violating lexicographical order
            if(s[i]>=s[i-1])
                length++;
            else//store current length sum to ans and start again by setting length to one
            {
                ans+=sum(length);
                length=1;
            }

        }
        ans+=sum(length);
        cout<<ans<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```